# Deleting an option value from a select box

Tags: javascript

I need your help.

I am still relatively new to javascript, and would like to accomplish the following:

Using the 'delete' key on my keyboard, I would like to able to delete the highlighted value from the drop down list depicted in this picture here:
[image]

and;

Using the delete key in the input box, I would like it to search for the value given in the input box and delete the option from out of the drop down box (as depicted in this picture here):[image]

Here is the HTML markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
function getvalue(x) {

document.getElementById('input').value = x

}

</script>

</head>

<body>

<input type="text" id="input">
<br>
<select id="list" onchange="getvalue(this.value)">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="ABC">ABC</option>
    <option value="DEF">DEF</option>
    <option value="GHI">GHI</option>
    <option value="JKL">JKL</option>
    <option value="MNO">MNO</option>
</select>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this pretty easily with jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/yFgZC/2/

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var value_to_delete = "ABC";

        $(document).keyup(function(e){
            if(e.keyCode == 46) {
                $("#list option").each(function() {
                    if($(this).attr("value") === value_to_delete) {
                        $(this).remove();   
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

You'll need to populate the `value_to_delete` variable, but that should be relatively straight forward.

Comment: What would a non-jQuery method be?